# Groups $P$ of order $p^5$ with $\Omega_1(P)=P$

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

I have been working with (particular) groups $P$ of order $p^5$. In fact, the ones that interest me the most are those that satisfy $$\langle x\in P\mid x^p=1\rangle=:\Omega_1(P)=P.$$ After a search in $\mathrm{GAP}$, I was a bit surprised that for a few primes $p>3$ there are exactly $9$ groups that satisfy it. Is it true in general for primes $p>3$?

My understanding is that the number of groups of order $p^5$ depends somehow on $p\bmod 12$, and they all are metabelian, but I find no reason for this pattern. Thanks in advance.

Comment: By Lazard correspondence, this is the same (for $p\ge 5$) as Lie nilpotent algebras of dimension 5 over $\mathbf{F}_p$. Now it its true over every field $k$ that there are exactly $9$ such Lie algebras. Whence the result. Reference: the [De Graaf 2007 paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jalgebra.2006.08.006). And in order $p^6$, there are 30 such ones (hence 30 groups of exponent $p$ and order $p^6$, for $p\ge 7$). In order $p^7$ and more, this will become dependent on $p$.

Comment: To complement YCor's comment, for $p \ge 5$, a group of order $p^5$ must be a regular $p$-group, so $\Omega_1(P) = P$ is equivalent to saying that $P$ has exponent $p$.

Comment: @SeanEberhard Ah thanks, indeed I had misread $\Omega_1(G)$ as the set generated by the set of elements of order $\le p$ rather than the subgroup it generates. That they coincide for a group of order $p^n$ when $n\le p$ (or more generally when the nilpotency length is $<n$) indeed follows from Lazard's correspondence.